# Who does this paragraph refer to?

Tags: meaning

I've been reading this [article](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/12/151204135513.htm).

And I came across this paragraph:

> We certainly need to further examine the meaning of these differences; yet, this is early evidence that sperm carries information about a man's weight. And our results imply that weight loss in fathers may influence the eating behaviour or their future children," says Romain Barrès.

I want to know, in this part:

> And our results imply that weight loss in fathers may influence the **eating behaviour or their future children**.

When it says the eating behaviour, who does the paragraph refers to? The father or future children?

How do I tell who the paragraph refers to?

Comment: This is just sad.

Comment: @Ricky: What is sad?

Comment: That people use that kind of style to write that kind of articles that other people actually kind of read. Sad, sad, sad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing this is just a typo. "influence the eating behaviour **or** their future children" should be "influence the eating behaviour **of** their future children".

This is a common typo and hard to spot in proofreading.

Comment: Reading more of the article, there is no need to guess, this is a typo.

Comment: Considering that letter 'R' is just above letter 'F' on the keyboard.

Comment: If it were *or* it would make no sense. But in answer to the OP's question it is the future children, whose eating behaviour is influenced.

Comment: @Stephie: You are right, but when it comes to translating scientific articles, you have to be far above than accurate.